# Disadvantage of using macro

Tags: c

In the following macro function, what is the issue:

```
#define STACK(x,y) (x=(int8_t)y)
```

In the above definition of macro, will it return any unexpected output

Comment: what do you think is the expected output ?

Comment: What if I use `STACK(5,6);`? Then It will be expanded as `(5=(int8_t)6);`

Comment: Weird macros like this one are never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Macros do not return a value, they are merely constructs which get replaced at the pre-processing step.

Now imagine calling your STACK macro like so:

```
STACK(x++, y++)
STACK(x, x++)
```

While it looks like a perfectly valid C syntax, it would be a syntax error on expansion of your particular macro in case 1, but would work as expected in case 2. It is therefore a confusing construct.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of macros should be avoided at nay price as they are unreadable, undebuggable  and error prone. Use inline functions instead and you will have the type checking and will be easy to maintain understand and debug. Your example is extremely trivial (even too trivial to make any sense)

```
inline uint8_t to_uint8_t(int x)
{
    return x;   // cast will done automaticly
}
```

or if you want macro do not do the assignment inside it

```
#define TO_UINT8_T(x)  ((uint8_t)(x))
```

and then assign the value in your code

```
x = to_uint8_t(y);

z = TO_UINT8_T(w);
```